# Iterate Array from on screen button (html)

Tags: html, arrays, for-loop, button, indexing

I'm trying to use an on screen button to move an array that displays images forward/backwards. However, I would like the carousel feature to remain in tact (so if I click it restarts the 8s period, if I do nothing it continues as is).

```
<script>

var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() 
{
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("radar");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
    {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;

    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  

    setTimeout(carousel, 8000); // number of seconds 

}


</script>
```

I have the on screen buttons built but am not sure how to move the index forward/backward on demand. The elements "radar" are just a series of images I'm using in a displayed loop.

Comment: I think it would help if you created a "working" sample in something like JSFiddle or Plunkr so we could examine your current behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To maintain the carousel and allow a button to move it forward\backward, you can use the **clearTimeout** function to clear the current callback then reset it.

When the button is used to to move the carousel forward, pass in a flag to reset the timeout.

Try this code:

```
<script>

var myIndex = 0;
var timeout = null;
carousel();

function carousel(dir)  // dir is null if timeout
{
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("radar");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
    {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex+= dir? dir : 1; //if dir is null, no button click, move carousel forward

    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
    if (myIndex < 0) {myIndex = x.length}
    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    
    if (dir) { clearTimeout(timeout); }  // button click, clear existing timeout

    timeout = setTimeout(carousel, 8000); // number of seconds 

}


</script>

<body>
    <button class="button button1" onclick="carousel(1)" >Next</button>
    <button class="button button1" onclick="carousel(-1)">Previous</button>
</body>
```

Comment: I posted a follow up question in the answers area because I couldn't copy/paste it back onto here in the same format.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for the help.